# AS3 Rotate 3D object around point in space

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air, stage3d

I use

```
appendRotation(_Y, Vector3D.Y_AXIS);
```

to rotate an object around its center. works fine.

when I want the object to rotate around the center of scene, I use

```
prependRotation( _Y, Vector3D.Y_AXIS , new Vector3D( 0, 0, 0 ) );
```

works fine.

but if I want to rotate object around some point in space like this:

```
prependRotation( _Y, Vector3D.Y_AXIS , new Vector3D( 10, 10, 10 ) );
```

it doesn't work, the object gets totaly distorted, can anyone give me a hint, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It could be resolved by adding your object into parent container. then
move object to proper position: appendTranslation(10, 10, 10), and then apply rotation to parent container: appendRotation(_Y, Vector3D.Y_AXIS).

Comment: That's how I did it, in order to avoid the problem, but why isn't it working the way it should?

Comment: I cant give explanation for sure. My feeling that issue occurs when we try to apply position and rotation transformation to object matrix3d.